# CSS3 Responsive Dropdown Menu is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, I want to use this menu here http://codepen.io/emredenx/pen/ojcxl

It does not work on blogger http://menuteste158.blogspot.com.br/ and I tried on several different templates as well.

I downloaded the codepen file and it worked perfectly... Then I thought that *the problem would be the blogger'* .. then I went to test in jsFiddle to make sure **(My reputation don't let me put more than 2 links, so i will put in the comment, sorry for it)** and did not work, I put the same codes of the files that I downloaded, and the result was the same with the blogger. how this can be possible?

> If it was just the blogger could be conflicts between codes, but I
>   tested in four different places (my computer, jsfiddle, codepen, blogger),  and the problem persists in two of them ...

I put comments on blogger with parts of the menu, to
facilitate a little more.

```
<!--menu-->

<!--script menu-->

<!--menu jquery-->
```

I've put the jquery after `<head>` and before the `</ body>` and had no difference too, and something else that I changed, only blogger, was this part of code:

```
if ($ (window) .width () <= mediasize) {
```

For this:

```
if ($ (window) .width () & lt; = mediasize) {
```

Now, I could not be more confused ... I do not know what to change, nor why. Are the same codes in different locations. they should work. This is not make sense to me now.

> Ps.: Andy Hoffman was right about why the code error in jsFiddle, but
>   still not working on blogger templetes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5f6s5tcz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu was not working on blogger, because this part of code in javascript:

`If ​​($ (window) .width () <= mediasize) {` and `if ($ (window) .width () & lt; = mediasize) {`

The code was showing this error:

```
*Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.*
```

Although I have made the change because of this error `The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.` that was appearing on blogger because some characters are not supported in XML code.

But there is a way to make that accepted, just putting a CDATA section. Like this:

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    (function($) {
      $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
        var cssmenu = $(this),
          settings = $.extend({
            format: "dropdown",
            sticky: false
          }, options);
        return this.each(function() {
          $(this).find(".button").on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
            var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
            if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
              mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
            } else {
              mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
              if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                mainmenu.find('ul').show();
              }
            }
          });
          cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
          multiTg = function() {
            cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
            cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
              if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
              } else {
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
              }
            });
          };
          if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
          else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
          if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
          resizeFix = function() {
            var mediasize = 700;
            if ($(window).width() > mediasize) {
              cssmenu.find('ul').show();
            }
            if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
              cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
            }
          };
          resizeFix();
          return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
        });
      };
    })(jQuery);

    (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
          format: "multitoggle"
        });
      });
    })(jQuery);
    //]]>
    </script>
```

And now the menu is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle works fine once you import jQuery and re-run the code.

[image]

Comment: :) You're right , it worked https://jsfiddle.net/carlavieirablogger/00w6ck8r/ . Just does not work on blogger ... Any idea why?

Comment: This looks promising: http://www.sneeit.com/2014/05/add-jquery-to-your-blogger-and-blogspot.html?m=0

Comment: You need to open your developer tools on your Blogger page and look for errors. If you see something like, `"$" is undefined`, this means there's no jQuery installed on your Blogger site. The link I posted in the last comment should show you how to import jQuery into Blogger. I think you're on your way to success.

Comment: I read the post, and do not have anything like this error in blogger ...

Can you tell me if these codes are the same thing? `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js` and `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`

Comment: I think you should use 2.1.4, though the two files are really similar. It's weird that Blogger actually recommends adding jQuery *after* the close of `</body>`. Check [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QUTyBQFwSEs/UhsEbxS6ujI/AAAAAAAAGy8/EB2mUhWgp0M/s1600/add-jquery-blogger.jpg) out. You should be all right adding this after `</body>`: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`. Try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: I put after `</body>` .. And nothing happened. It has an error *Uncaught SyntaxError: missing) after argument list* in this line `cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class='submenu-button'></span>')`
but it looks fine to me... i search now about this error but did not find anything like mine...

Comment: The error is legitimate. On line 5372, there is a JavaScript line beginning `return this.each(function() {` You must have included the menu code in a place where that function was still opened. This would cause the `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing) after argument list` error you saw. You have to make sure that no other code is surrounding your menu plugin. You'll have to try it again.